# Swift Link Button to Controller

Tags: ios, button, uiview, swift

I have a programatically made button, which i would like to connect it to an action so that it goes straight to another view when I click it. Normally i would just control + drag. but i can't since it programatically made. How would i link this code to my "ViewController" so when i click it, the ViewController(log-in screen) Pops up.

The Code is here, and its from https://github.com/mamaral/Onboard

```
let thirdPage: OnboardingContentViewController = OnboardingContentViewController(title: "Seriously Though", body: "Kudos to the photographer.", image: UIImage(named:"yellow"), buttonText: "Let's Get Started"){  //Enter Action Here//
```

I'm not sure whether this part is necessary to help you, but i'll link it just in case

```
if (countElements(self.buttonText) != 0) {
            var actionButton: UIButton = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake((CGRectGetMaxX(self.view.frame) / 2) - (contentWidth / 2), CGRectGetMaxY(self.view.frame) - kDefaultMainPageControlHeight - kDefaultActionButtonHeight - self.bottomPadding, contentWidth, kDefaultActionButtonHeight))
            actionButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont .systemFontOfSize(24)
            actionButton.setTitle(self.buttonText, forState: .Normal)
            actionButton.setTitleColor(self.buttonTextColor, forState: .Normal)
            actionButton.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
            self.view.addSubview(actionButton)
```

Comment: Don't ever post links to github repos. No one is going to look through all of your code. Pin down your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Going off of this line of code:

```
actionButton.addTarget(self, action: "handleButtonPressed", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

If it isn't working, you probably forgot to add an actual function titled "handleButtonPressed"--something like this:

```
func handleButtonPressed() {
    // Show the view that needs showing
}
```